# Laravel Eloquent create null field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $connection = 'pos';

    public function __construct()
    {
        config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'pos_1']);
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

Product::create(['name' => 'Snack']);
```

on my db id=1, name=null, created_at='2016-06-26 18:30:24', updated_at='2016-06-26 18:30:24', deleted_at=null

Why name=null?

---

**Update post**

works when I use

```
$p = new Product();
$p->name = 'Snack';
$p->save();
```

but why `Product::create(['name' => 'Snack']);` fill as null ?

---

**Update post(solved)**

ah I missing pass array as parameter on that constructor.

```
        public function __construct(array $attributes)
        {
            config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'pos_1']);
            parent::__construct($attributes);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the reason is that you again don't run parent constructor.

Instead of:

```
public function __construct()
{
    config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'pos_1']);
}
```

you should use:

```
public function __construct()
{
    config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'pos_1']);
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Be aware that for your Eloquent Model you have also `connection` property, so you could probably set also name of database connection.

Comment: Do you have any mutator method? I mean do you have setNameAttribute method defined for your class?

Comment: What's the type for `name` column? Do you use any database triggers?

Comment: varchar, no trigger, just simple table sir, this is not happen when use default connection

Comment: updated Sir, this is works but without method create, may u know why?